# Interface Extension method to Concrete implementations

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, interface, extension-methods

I know that title is a bit vague, but it's the best I could come up with.

I have this property

```
public string SSN { get; set; }
```

I also have an extension method:

```
public static string FormatSSN(this string ssn)
{
    return ssn..... // Format logic
}
```

So now I can do:

```
@Model.SSN.FormatSSN()
```

Cool, but basic stuff. The problem is now I have a second client of my app who needs `FormatSSN()` to do different stuff.

How do I `interface` such an `extension method` so that I can `inject` different implementations of it based on who the client is?

Comment: Can't you just pass an argument?

Comment: Pass an argument? What do you mean by that? Like have a huge switch statement in each of my extension methods to determine which implementation to use?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I interface such an extension method so that I can inject different implementations of it based on who the client is?

You can't have an extension method that an interface recognizes, because the extension method is really static and is tied to the class.

If you want to make it so you can inject things, pass in a `Func` or an `Action` with the appropriate parameters.

For example,

```
int DoSomethingToSSN(Func<string,string> myFormatSSNAction){
   var myssn = "115454564" 
   return myFormatSSNAction(myssn);
}


public static string FormatSSN(string ssn)
{
    return ssn..... // Format logic
}
```

Then you would call it like `DoSomethingToSSN(FormatSSN)`

Comment: Can you please give a more concrete example?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
public static string FormatSSN(this string ssn, string clientIdentity)
{
    switch (clientIdentity)
    {
        case "client1Identifier":
            return ssn..... // Format logic for client 1
            break;
        case "client2Identifier":
            return ssn..... // Format logic for client 2
            break;
        default:
            return ssn..... // Default Format logic
            break;
    }
}
```

And

```
@Model.SSN.FormatSSN(@Model.ClientIdentifier)
```

Comment: I think this is the prettiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

That can be obvious, but as long as you can store cliencode (let's in web.config) then you can add an if statement.
As static functions aren't nice to decouple, the other solution is have a factory method which will provide exact function based on customer.

factroy example below:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public interface ISsnFormater
    {
        string Format(string input);
    }

    public class ClientOneFormater : ISsnFormater
    {
        public string Format(string input)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class ClientTwoFormater : ISsnFormater
    {
        public string Format(string input)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class FormaterFactory
    {
        public ISsnFormater GetFormaterFor(string customerName)
        {
            switch (customerName)
            {
                case "One":
                    return new ClientOneFormater();

                case "Two":
                    return new ClientTwoFormater();
            }

            throw  new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }

}
```